# Magick++ - Reading JPEG2000 images

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg2000, magick++

I'm trying to read JPEG2000 images in Magick++ (the C++ API of ImageMagick). To read an image I use the following code:

```
Image img("path/to/my/image.jp2");
```

But when I try to do this, ImageMagick throws an Exception and doesn´t load the image.
I extract the images out of PDF files. Could it be that something´s different to normal JPEG2000 images? To extract the images I read the stream of Image objects which have a JPXDecode-filter and save them to a file.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick uses a package called JasPer to handle JPEG2000's. According to the wikipedia page on [OpenJpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJPEG), JasPer does not completely support the JPEG2000 specification. I have several extrected JPEG2000 that open fine in QuickTime, but fail to  decode with ImageMagick.

I have had better results using OpenJpeg to decode the the Jpeg2000. The interface is less flexible, it will convert to PNG and BMP.